# Flutter onPanStart invokes late when the widget is wrapped inside InteractiveViewer

Tags: flutter, dart

I just have a simple container which has a resize handle on center right which means the container can be resized using that handle. It is wrapped inside `InteractiveViewer` widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _width = 300;
  double _height = 200;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final m = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          height: m.size.height,
          width: m.size.width,
          child: InteractiveViewer(
            maxScale: 30,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(height: _height, width: _width, color: Colors.red),
                Positioned(
                  top: _height / 2 - 10,
                  left: _width - 20,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onPanStart: (details) {
                      print("PAN STARTED");
                    },
                    onPanUpdate: (details) {
                      final delta = details.delta;
                      setState(() {
                        _width = _width + delta.dx;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(height: 20, width: 20, color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is `onPanStart` invokes a lot late after the initial drag. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: This problem cannot be replicated in DartPad. In DartPad it works fine. The problem can only be seen in simulators/phones.

Answer (score 3):

I found a fix for this issue. Just use Listener instead of GestureDetector (it has substitutes for the most parameters: onPanStart -> onPointerDown, onPanUpdate -> onPointerMove). With Listener, there will be no delay.

Minimum code example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IssueExamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IssueExamplePageState createState() => _IssueExamplePageState();
}

class _IssueExamplePageState extends State<IssueExamplePage> {
  bool drawingBlocked = false;
  List<Offset> points;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: InteractiveViewer(
            child: AbsorbPointer(
              absorbing: drawingBlocked,
              child: Listener(
                 onPointerMove: (details) {
                  RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
                  Offset cursorLocation = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.localPosition);

                  setState(() {
                    points = List.of(points)..add(cursorLocation);
                  });
                },
                child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: MyPainter(points),
                  size: Size.infinite
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.clear),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                points = [];
              });
            }
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(drawingBlocked? CupertinoIcons.hand_raised_fill : CupertinoIcons.hand_raised),
            onPressed: () {
              drawingBlocked = !drawingBlocked;
            }
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  MyPainter(this.points);
  List<Offset> points;
  Paint paintBrush = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.blue
    ..strokeWidth = 5
    ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], paintBrush);
    }
  }
  
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyPainter oldDelegate) {
    return points != oldDelegate.points;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just saved me a lot of trouble :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: you really saved me a lot of hours debugging, how is it possible that one lags and not the other?